# Large number of form controls with ngrx

Tags: ngrx, angular-reactive-forms

I recently learn NgRx (actually still trying to learn) and updating our existing projects to Angular 5 and ngrx structure. So far so good but one of our pages got a data table with more than 1k+ form fields in it.

I normally was using reactive forms to populating form fields from state slice and updating changes to state when user send the form but with that much of form fields creating form controls probably will be very costly and don't want to slow down that page and seems like it is not ok to just use basic text boxes and ngModel with NgRx structure

How can I solve that problem in NgRx way. Thank you in advance

Comment: Holy foot, what kind of application has a form with more than 1000 form fields? Anyway, as for your question, using either reactive form or template-driven form will create the same amount of `FormControl` objects, they differ in how much flexibity they offer and whether you have to manually instantiate the `FormControl`s yourself , reactive form is best suited for dynamic form. ngrx store is just a state manager, very similar to redux store (ngrx store is inspired by redux store btw), so there is not really a "ngrx way"

Comment: Yes template driven or reactive both creating those form objects and that page is for supplier discounts so there are more than thousand suppliers in which user able to filter out and update. Old version using ngModel for updating those form fields. (I think basic text fields and ngModel) was not create that much of overhead. But using formControls just scares me. Probably it would be best to put all of those inside a form array and just listen changes.

Comment: Well, first of all, using `ngModel`, angular automatically creates `FormControl`s and attaches them to your `input` HTML elements, so if you are using reactive form, you have to do all that yourself, so logically, it should not cause any performance problem. Again, don't optimize prematurely, measure and see if reactive form causes performance problem as compared to template driven form, but I am very sure using reactive form will not make your form slow

Comment: Himm I did not know using ngModel was creating form control creation but anyway, the other problem is to create all those form controls and add them to a form group. Probably I should do that with a loop as well (creating all of them one by one not possible)
Thanks, if you answer question I will mark as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use template driven form (By using `ngModel` directives on `input` elements), angular automatically creates `FormControl`s on your behalf and attaches them to all registered `input` HTML elements, and then register these `FormControl`s with the `NgForm` directly that angular creates and attaches to the `form` element for you. On the other hand, if you choose to use reactive form, you, yourself, have to explicitly create the top level `FormGroup` and any `FormControl`s or `FormArray`s, and register these `FormControl`s and `FormArray`s with the parent `FormGroup` and manually bind these to your `form` element and any `input` elements you want angular to keep an eye on. So logically, there should not be any notable difference in terms of performance. You also should not make any assumption about the performance problem that might by caused by using reactive form, measuring is your best answer in this case. But using reactive allows greater control and flexibility over your form

ngrx store is just a state manager, it is very similar to redux store, in fact, ngrx store is inspired by redux store, in one word, ngrx store allows you to put all your app states into a central location, so it is easier to manage and retrieve, so you don't really have to use it if you don't need to, there is not really a "ngrx way" of doing things